# How to access nested child with angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs, nested, parent-child

Actually i am trying to make a category and sub-category page where categories can have many sub_categories and they can have sub_categories;
JSON data is coming fine with spring mvc but i don't know much about angularJS. Can anyone please help me with it. Please ask if you require more details.
Thanks in advance.

**JSON DATA**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "ELECTRONICS",
        "description": null,
        "sub_categories": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Men's Store",
                "description": null,
                "sub_categories": [
                    {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Men's Store",
                    "description": null,
                    "sub_categories": [
                        {
                            "id": 4,
                            "name": "Men's Store",
                            "description": null,
                            "sub_categories": []
                            }

                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

there are going to be unknown no of childs for 'sub_categories'. I am showing this data to table like this:

**HTML**

```
<tbody id="tr_body">
<tr
    ng-repeat="mycategory in category | filter: searchKeyword | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort">
    <td><label class="checkbox m-n i-checks"><input
            type="checkbox" name="cat[]"><i></i></label></td>
    <td>{{mycategory.name}}</td>
    <td>{{mycategory.description}}</td>
    <td><a href="#" ng-click="removeRow(mycategory.id)"><i
        class="fa fa-pencil text-success"
        ></i></a> <a href="#" ng-click="removeRow(mycategory.id)"><i
        class="fa fa-times text-danger"
        ></i></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

**AngularJS Script**

```
ajaxApp.controller("CategoryCtrl", [ '$scope', '$http',function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.category = [];
    var result = $http.get('/json-admin-categories-c');
    result.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        $scope.category = data;
    });
    result.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("failure message: " + JSON.stringify({
            data : data
        }));
    });
    }
]);
```

Comment: do  a search for angular recursive directive. Should find lots of results

Comment: nice answer... let me check thanks..

Comment: Sorry searched but didn't find any answer..if you can find any please share the link here